# app preDexDebug error in android studio

Tags: android, gradle

I got this error and I don't know why,
if someone know how to fix it it will be awesome.

here is the complete error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: google search knows the fix ... it's pointing to similar question here on SO

Comment: I didn't understand the solution that i found  in google
 if you know something it will be great

Comment: use gradlew assemble --info to have a detailed stacktrace

Comment: I don't understand what to do...

Comment: search your bottom toolbar,there is a tab name terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this comandline for more detail:

```
gradlew assemble -info
```

---

[image]

Comment: A picture may paint a thousand words, but a picture which should be text paints a thousand annoyed developers who can't copy/paste text from an image. What happens if the image goes dead - your answer will be useless.

Comment: Thx.Where are you come from!